# Verilog: wire value not updated

Tags: verilog

I have the following MWE:

```
module test(
    input wire clock,
    input wire start
);

reg [7:0] x = 8'b10101010;
reg processing = 0;
wire [7:0] x_wire0 = x;
wire [7:0] x_wire1 = {4'hf, x};
wire [11:0] x_wire2 = {4'hf, x};

always @(posedge clock) begin
   if (start & ~processing) begin
       x = 8'h0f;
       processing = 1;
   end

   $display("---> x=%h x_wire0=%h x_wire1=%h x_wire2=%h",
       x, x_wire0, x_wire1, x_wire2);
end
endmodule
```

with the testbench

```
module test_test();

reg clock = 0;
reg start = 0;

test test(
    .clock(clock),
    .start(start)
);

always #5 clock = ~clock;

initial begin
    $monitor("%b %b", clock, start);

    #20 start = 1;
    #20 start = 0;

    #200 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

which using Icarus Verilog 0.9.7 gives me the output

```
0 0
---> x=aa x_wire0=aa x_wire1=aa x_wire2=faa
1 0
0 0
---> x=aa x_wire0=aa x_wire1=aa x_wire2=faa
1 0
0 1
---> x=0f x_wire0=0f x_wire1=aa x_wire2=f0f
1 1
0 1
---> x=0f x_wire0=0f x_wire1=0f x_wire2=f0f
1 1
0 0
...
```

I wonder why x_wire1 is not updated until the next clock tick and whether there are any rules (of thumb) to avoid these kind of situations.
If I use a "#0" before the display command, it is updated.

Comment: There are blocking assignments in the same `always` block that have  `x_wire1` on their RHS. I did not include that code in the example code to keep it minimal. I once read that nonblocking assignments and blocking assignments should not be mixed in the same `always` block.

Comment: You should not mix blocking and non-blocking assignments to the _same_ variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `$display` to `$strobe`, you will get the results you are looking for. It truly is a race condition in simulation if the wires have a chance to get updated before the `$display`. `$strobe` delays its output until the end of the time slot after the wires have settled. The assignments to the wires are essentially independent processes.

Another option is to use non-blocking assignments to `x`. You should always use non-block assignments to variables in sequential logic that will be read by another process anyways. Then your $display is always printing values from the previous clock cycle.

And finally, you can use another `always` block just for the `$display` statement the uses the negative edge of the clock.

Comment: My problem is that I (blocking) assign to `x` and below use wires that depend on `x` (like `x_wire1`). There must be some way to know when the wires have a stable state before they are used?!

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain why you need a statement like `x_wire0 = x;` in your design. Maybe you could replace these with function calls. In SystemVerilog, you would use a `let` statement.